# Unable to determine cause of syntax error

Tags: mysql

I am running an insert query to add data into my database but I get the following error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s' at line 1")"

I have reviewed the code but unable to determine why

```
cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO footballtest(`codmeci` ,`datameci`,`orameci` ,`sezonul` ,`etapa` ,`txtechipa1`,`txtechipa2` ,`scor1` ,`scor2` ,`scorp1` ,`scorp2` ,`codechipa1` ,`codechipa2` ,`cotaa` ,`cotae`,`cotad`,`cotao` ,`cotau` ,`suth` ,`suta` ,`sutht`,`sutat` ,`corh` ,`cora` ,`foulsh` ,`foulsa` ,`yellowh`,`yellowa` ,`ballph`,`ballpa` ,`mgolh` ,`mgola` ,`mgol`) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"), (row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[9],row[10],row[13],row[14],row[16],row[17],row[18],row[19],row[20],row[29],row[30],row[31],row[32],row[33],row[34],row[35],row[36],row[37],row[38],row[39],row[40],row[57],row[58],row[59])
```

Comment: Remove the `)` after the closing double quote of the query string.  Your syntax is off.

Comment: i think you should provide more code like table structure and your client side code.

Comment: Are you sure your statement isnt too long?

Comment: @BugFinder i think Tim has made a correct point here.. `%s,%s,%s)") <--- , (row[0],row[1],` The `)` seams it should not be there, wierd that Python does not give a parse error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes taking a large problem and simplifying it can reveal what the problem is.  Here is your insert, but using only three columns:

```
sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO footballtest(codmeci, datameci, orameci) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
cursor.execute(sql, (row[0], row[1], row[2]))
```

Note carefully that the pattern is:

```
cursor.execute(<some SQL string>, (some CSV tuple of values to bind))
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland For whatever reason, I thought I saw the OP tagged with SQLite (where my original answer would have worked).

Comment: Not AFAIK.  The second parameter, after the query string, is a tuple.

Comment: *"The second parameter, after the query string, is a tuple"* indeed the manual indeed mention that *"cursor.execute(operation, **params=None**, multi=False) This method executes the given database operation (query or command). **The parameters found in the tuple or dictionary params** are bound to the variables in the operation. Specify variables using %s or %(name)s parameter style (that is, using format or pyformat style). execute() returns an iterator if multi is True.  "* Which offcource i totally mist the first time reading it.